# Fatal error: spawn ENOENT node.js and grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Hi for responsive images i downloaded project from

https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images

i installed all those things what they have mentioned...

whenever i say grunt it saying fallowing error:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
  >> 3 files lint free.

  Running "clean:tests" (clean) task
 Cleaning "tmp"...OK

 Running "responsive_images:default_options" (responsive_images) task
 Fatal error: spawn ENOENT
```

why i am getting this error pla tellme...

Thnk you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely because you don't have imagemagick installed: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

See the FAQ on that plugin: https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images#faq

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same error as you yesterday, and I found that I had installed wrong version of node.js eventually.

I'm using 64-bit Windows,but I had installed 32bit version Node.js.
I could install it and it seems working normally, but when I tried to compile existing project,  the error message had been shown.

But after I re-install 64-bit version of Node.js, all error had been solved.

If you are using 64bit OS, better to check the version is correct or not.